# phpmyadmin/import.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import MySql database after emptying the current but as i click on **go** button i get this error

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/import.php was not found on this server.

I have checked that *import.php* is present in *D:\wamp\apps\sqlbuddy1.3.3* but i am still getting this error. not sure about the error that why i am getting this file missing error because previously the system was working fine.

Note: I tried to search but didn't find any solution.

I have done this for database import
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have imported import.php or import.sql in MySql Database?

Comment: Im assuming this is being run locally on your computer, why dont you try xampp.

Comment: If import.php is present in this - D:\wamp\apps\sqlbuddy1.3.3, then why are you accessing it from this - /phpmyadmin/import.php, access it from this - D:\wamp\apps\sqlbuddy1.3.3/import.php

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i have check in wamp that i have import.php in D:\wamp\apps\sqlbuddy1.3.3

Comment: @TarangP php export code? where it is?

Comment: Sorry I read wrong. @MuhammadFaizanKhan

Comment: I have also add pictures of my database import procedures

Comment: I have the same problem with MAMP. Tried increasing `post_max_size`, but it didn't fix it for me. I ended up using MySQLWorkbench for the import.